# How to send sms or make phone call on a real android device from PC?

Tags: android, connection, sms

Trying to figure out is it possible to send sms or make phone call from PC to a real device.

I know how to do it using an Emulator.   tty localhost port...

Does real device got a port?

I just started learning Android stuff.So, thx for helping ^_^!

Answer (score 0):

One way to communicate between a PC and a phone would be if they were both on the same local network, perhaps both connected to the same WiFi router. When I've had to do this in the past I've looked in my router control panel to see the IP addresses allocated to the attached devices, but there are other ways to do it.

Of course you'd need to write an Android app to actually send the SMS, that's a different issue.