# Call to real device from adb

Tags: android, adb, phone-call

Is it possible make a call (call phone) to real device? 
I called to emulator via adb, but I want to try in a real device.

I checked the question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535490/how-to-simulate-incoming-calls-on-a-real-device) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595182/how-to-send-sms-or-make-phone-call-on-a-real-android-device-from-pc) , but them not resolve anything.

Comment: This is not a question about code, I want to call to real device, like  "gsm call 123456" in telnet to call to a android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if below adb shell code can be useful for you to make call in real device.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel: 1234567890
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make call to real device from emulator.

Using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) Telephony section you can spoof voice call or sms between **emulators** not in real device. This Telephony is under "**Emulator Controls**" section, which means this is only for the emulators.

Follow the below steps as mentioned in http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#calling

> To initiate a simulated voice call to another emulator instance:
>   1. Launch the dialer application on the originating emulator instance. 
>  2. As the number to dial, enter the console port number of the instance you'd like to call. You can determine the console port number of the target instance by checking its window title, where the console port number is reported as "Android Emulator ().
>  3. Press "Dial". A new inbound call appears in the target emulator instance.
>   To send an SMS message to another emulator instance, launch the SMS application (if available). Specify the console port number of the target emulator instance as as the SMS address, enter the message text, and send the message. The message is delivered to the target emulator instance.

Comment: I came to a conclusión that it is not possible to call a real device from telnet or adb.